# Configurable area in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, api, configuration

Currently I am working on an angular web app whose backend is going to be in ASP.NET MVC. The API is not made yet so for now I want to use some static json files etc. Just to get an application up and running and then later I want to change the urls to live RESTful API. My question is what is the best way of going about it? I mean I am going to hand it over to the backend developer where he should just go to a specific file and change urls to the live API.

One way that I think would be nice will be to use value method on the app module or maybe configure it like $routeProvider allows us. I want to know what would be the best practice.

For example:

```
app.value('API', {
  getAllThings: 'api/allThings.json',
  createThing: 'api/createThing.json'
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Value seems sensible for API urls.
You can use also providers which Are configurable before app init.
For testing,you can use fake API thanks to httpbackend service.
You can configure static json in it and Use flush to retrieve data.